# How to compare the elements of an array from the same object in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a document collection with the below data

```
[{
_id:ObjectId(),
status:"created",
users:[{
email:"xyz@gmail.com",
role:"admin"
},
{
email:"abc@gmail.com",
role:"admin"
},
{
email:"abc@gmail.com",
role:"user"
}]
},
{
_id:ObjectId(),
status:"created",
users:[{
email:"pqr@gmail.com",
role:"admin"
},
{
email:"abc@gmail.com",
role:"admin"
},
{
email:"pqr@gmail.com",
role:"user"
}]
}]
```

I want to fetch the count of documents which have the user with both "admin" and "user" roles and the status is "created". Now I'm trying to match the email id and also the role.

```
db.documents.aggregate([
       {"$match":{
           "status":"created",
    "$expr":{
      "$eq":[
        {"$size":{"$setIntersection":["$users.email_id","$users.email_id"]}},
        0
      ]
    }
  }},
    ])
```

Is there any way to compare the elements of the array from the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to fetch the *count of documents* which have the *user* with both
>   "admin" and "user" roles and the *status* is "created". Now I'm trying
>   to match the *email* id and also the role.

You can use an aggregation *or* a find query as follows:

```
var MATCH_EMAIL = "abc@gmail.com"

db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $and: [ { status: "created" } , { "users": { $elemMatch: { role: "admin", email: MATCH_EMAIL } } } ],
          "users": { $elemMatch: { role: "user", email: MATCH_EMAIL } } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $count: "Count" 
  }
] )

// -- or --

db.collection.find( { 
    $and: [ { status: "created" } , { "users": { $elemMatch: { role: "admin", email: MATCH_EMAIL } } } ],
    "users": { $elemMatch: { role: "user", email: MATCH_EMAIL } } 
} ).count()
```

Note the query filter is same in both cases. The aggregation returns a result document like `{ "Count" : 1 }`, but the *find* query returns just the count value, like `1`.

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

Updated code to have the same email for "user" and "admin" riles.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $and: [ { status: "created" } , { "users.role": "admin" } ],
          "users.role": "user"
      } 
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$users" 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { _id: "$_id", email: "$users.email" },
          roles: { $push: "$users.role" }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $match: { 
          $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$roles" }, 1 ] } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $count: "Count with user+admin roles and same email" 
  }
] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works but I needed the email id to be dynamic. I don't have the email Id to compare. Is there any way to compare the email I'd of user with role "admin" with the role "user"? $user.email_id or anything?

Comment: I have added the aggregation for that. I think thats what you are looking for.